# Execute a command after pod startup without overriding image entrypoint

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, apache-flink

I want to know if there is any solution in order to submit a flink job to a kubernetes cluster.

In the jobmanager deployment file after startup I tried to add a command option to my jobmanager pod but I realized that the command I passed override the image entrypoint.

So I want to know if there is a solution to do so?

Comment: I'd probably use a separate Kubernetes Job for a one-off task like this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you provide a `command` and/or its `args`, it overrides the original image's `Entrypoint` and/or `Cmd`. If you want to know how exactly it happens, please refer to [this fragment of the official kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes).

If you want to run some additional command immediatelly after your `Pod` startup, you can do it with a `postStart` handler, which usage is presented in [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers):

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: lifecycle-demo
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - name: lifecycle-demo-container
>     image: nginx
>     lifecycle:
>       postStart:
>         exec:
>           command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
>       preStop:
>         exec:
>           command: ["/bin/sh","-c","nginx -s quit; while killall -0 nginx; do sleep 1; done"]
> ```

Comment: but  it says: "There is no guarantee, however, that the postStart handler is called before the Container's entrypoint is called"

Comment: Is it necessary that it is always called before the container's entrypoint ? I guess it shouln't be a problem even when it is called right after it. Anyway, I'm not aware of any alternative way of running an additional command without overwriting the image entrypoint. This is probably the only way kubernetes provides.

Answer (score -1):

Not specifically. Really it's up to your application. The only thing Kubernetes can control is what the initial command run inside the container is and there can only be one of those.